# Statistical Power depending on Level of Measurement

Tags: statistical-power, genetics

It is intuitively clear that a statistical analysis based on continuous data is more informative (i.e. has more statistical power) than if the same data is transformed into a categorical variable based on a certain threshold value.

Could somebody please point me to a literature reference for this simple statement, preferably a research article from genetic or medical science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some refs (nothing from genetics, I'm afraid):

http://www.unc.edu/~rcm/psy282/cohen.1983.pdf
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1458573/
http://www.psychology.sunysb.edu/attachment/measures/content/maccallum_on_dichotomizing.pdf

And a (mild) defense of dichotomization: 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19968397